# Double action after meeting condition

Tags: javascript

I have to add a line to an existing code, but I am not sure if this is the right way.

This is the existing code

```
if (window.total_time <= window.cutOffTime) {
    tos = TrackingLogTime(tos.split(":").reverse());
    ga("send", "event", "Time", "Log", tos)
} else {
    window.clearInterval(window.stIntervalObj)
}
```

and I need to add this action

```
ga("newTracker.send", "event", "Time", "Log", tos)
```

Is it possible to do it like this

```
if (window.total_time <= window.cutOffTime) {
    tos = TrackingLogTime(tos.split(":").reverse());
    ga("send", "event", "Time", "Log", tos) && ga("newTracker.send", "event", "Time", "Log", tos)
} else {
    window.clearInterval(window.stIntervalObj)
}
```

Comment: And what `&&` is supposed to do you think?

Comment: @c-smile people find stuff on the internet from questionable sources - they're just trying to get things to work.

Comment: That's true. I have done more with php, so the idea was coming from that.

Comment: @WendiT `&&` operator in JS and PHP does the same so is the question: what you want it to do here?

Comment: @c-smile What I want to achieve is sending event data to two different Google Analytics accounts. So both actions must always be sent when the condition is met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your new function call as a separate statement:

```
if (window.total_time <= window.cutOffTime) {
    tos = TrackingLogTime(tos.split(":").reverse());
    ga("send", "event", "Time", "Log", tos);
    ga("newTracker.send", "event", "Time", "Log", tos);
} else {
    window.clearInterval(window.stIntervalObj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. At least I'm sure now.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the line of code after the previous one:

```
if (window.total_time <= window.cutOffTime) {
    tos = TrackingLogTime(tos.split(":").reverse());
    ga("send", "event", "Time", "Log", tos);
    ga("newTracker.send", "event", "Time", "Log", tos);
} else {
    window.clearInterval(window.stIntervalObj);
}
```

The operator `&&`, is actually used to "combine" two booleans so to speak, in an `if` statement, for example:

```js
var name = prompt("What is your name? ");
if(name[0] == "A" && name[1] == "J"){
    alert("Hello A.J.!");
}else{
  alert("You are not A.J.");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes it is possible, but I'm not sure if it will do what you expect. It will execute the first call to the ga() function. If the return value from that can be evaluated as false, then it will NOT execute the second call to the ga() function. If the first one returns a value that can be evaluated as true, then the second one will also be executed. This is the "short-circuiting" of the && operator coming into play. If the return value from the first call is falsey, then it's impossible for the entire statement to be true, so it stops evaluating it.

If you want both calls to always be executed, then the best way would be to have them as separate statements, as the other answers have suggested.

Comment: Just to understand this, do I separate the statements with an ; ?

Comment: Yep, separate them with a semicolon. I would also recommend putting them on separate lines, to make it easier to read, but that's not required.